# However, import sklearn still gives me error. More details are given below. How do i resolve this?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, openmp

I am using python3.6 (python3.8 was tried earlier for the same problem) on windows 7. I have installed joblib==0.14.0, numpy==1.17.4, scikit-learn==0.22 and scipy==1.3.3 for some Machine Learning project.

The error message i get when i try to import sklearn is:

```
    from ._openmp_helpers import _openmp_parallelism_enabled
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Kindly advise how to resolve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Try installing ```MS C++ 2019```. It'll solve your problem. But first of all, try with the 64-bit version of Python. I'm afraid you're using 32-bit version for it.

Comment: This packaging issue is being tracked at: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15899

In the mean time you can install scikt-learn from conda-forge:

`conda install conda-forge::scikit-learn`

Answer (score 2):

So it could be linked with missing OpenMP and we think that a quick fix will be to install VC++ (2015, 2017, 2019): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads. Select the architecture of your system (32 bits -> x86; 64 bits -> x64)

More information will be given there: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15899