# "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _openmp_helpers"?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I tried to import `resample_img` from `nilearn.image` to use in resampling some medical image.

```
import nibabel as nib
import nibabel.processing
from nilearn.image import resample_img

img = nib.load('./dicom_to_nifti.nii')
new_img = nibabel.processing.resample_to_output(img, (2, 2, 2))
new_img.to_filename('nifti_2_2_2')
```

However I keep getting this error that says that it can't find the sklearn module? I've installed it already via `pip install sklearn`. I've even tried to uninstall everything and get a fresh install but the same problem pops up. I'm certain it's either I'm doing something wrong, or there's something wrong with the packages.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 9, in <module>
    from nilearn.image import resample_img
    _check_module_dependencies()
  File "C:\Users\craig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nilearn\version.py", line 111, in _check_module_dependencies
    _import_module_with_version_check(
  File "C:\Users\craig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nilearn\version.py", line 60, in _import_module_with_version_check
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\craig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
  File "C:\Users\craig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_show_versions.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._openmp_helpers import _openmp_parallelism_enabled
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _openmp_helpers: The specified module could not be found.. Module "sklearn" could not be found. See http://nilearn.github.io/introduction.html#installation for installation information.
PS C:\Users\craig\Documents\Files\westmead_radiomics> python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from nilearn.image import resample_img
  File "C:\Users\craig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nilearn\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    _check_module_dependencies()
  File "C:\Users\craig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nilearn\version.py", line 111, in _check_module_dependencies
    _import_module_with_version_check(
  File "C:\Users\craig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nilearn\version.py", line 60, in _import_module_with_version_check
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\craig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
  File "C:\Users\craig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_show_versions.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._openmp_helpers import _openmp_parallelism_enabled
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _openmp_helpers: The specified module could not be found.. Module "sklearn" could not be found. See http://nilearn.github.io/introduction.html#installation for installation information.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No idea but looks like a similar question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59206367/however-import-sklearn-still-gives-me-error-more-details-are-given-below-how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `nilearn` seems to depend on `sklearn`. The problem comes from the lack of `_openmp_helpers.py` file in where `pip` looks for it when importing `sklearn`.

I had a similar one and solved it through downgrading `sklearn` below 0.22. This required getting it from the PyPI repository:

https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/0.21.3/#files

and was somewhat a hassle, since I had to install Python 3.7 (latest that seems to work with sklearn 0.21.3), and a C++ compiler to build the `sklearn` (but you could try to use `.whl` installation instead).

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! I didn't have to use the C++ compiler or anything. I just used `pip install` to install the older version, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and followed the advice from [However, import sklearn still gives me error. More details are given below. How do i resolve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59206367/however-import-sklearn-still-gives-me-error-more-details-are-given-below-how).

After installing "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019" and a reboot, sklearn 0.22 works fine.

```
> python -c "import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()"

System:
    python: 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
executable: python.exe
   machine: Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0

Python dependencies:
       pip: 19.3.1
setuptools: 40.8.0
   sklearn: 0.22
     numpy: 1.18.0
     scipy: 1.4.1
    Cython: None
    pandas: 0.25.3
matplotlib: 3.1.2
    joblib: 0.14.1

Built with OpenMP: True
```

Comment: It will be solved in scikit-learn 0.22.1 but in the meanwhile, this is one of the possible fix (another one is to install from conda-forge channel)