# Importing sklearn.linear_model gives an error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have used

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

and getting the following errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/PyProjects/LRtest.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
  File "F:\PyProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
  File "F:\PyProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_show_versions.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._openmp_helpers import _openmp_parallelism_enabled
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

As recommended on earlier questions:

I have uninstalled numpy, sklearn, scikit-learn, scipy and also reinstalled them.

But that does not seem to work for my problem.

Can you tell what does this mean? And also recommend how to solve this?

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am using

Windows 10, PyCharm Pro 2019-3, Python v3.6, and lib versions given in the image

[image: Image describing lib versions used]

Comment: Maybe this might help? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794. Also some more information would be nice (operating system, python version, sklearn version, and the specific chain of commands/steps you used to build your environment)

Comment: Corrected as you asked. The link you mentioned doesn't help. @JayMody

Comment: I'm having trouble recreating the error on windows 10, with python 3.7 and the same sci-kit learn version, one thing I might try is downgrading the version of sci-kit learn to 0.21 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59206390/importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-openmp-helpers)

Answer (score 0):

The package is called scikit-learn, not sklearn. From inside of Python, it is called sklearn. How do you have an entry for sklearn in your package list there with version 0?

Try uninstalling 'sklearn'. You already have the real scikit-learn, so maybe it will do the right thing once the false package is removed.

If that doesn't work, I would create a new python environment from scratch and reinstall the right packages there...
https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

That way you know that you're starting with a clean slate.

Answer (score 0):

First, uninstall numpy and scipy from your command prompt.

```
pip uninstall numpy

pip uninstall scipy
```

After that install numpy and scipy from this website.

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy