# ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-learn, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, scikit-learn

While I running this command on command prompt

```
C:\Users\Sayan Saha>pip install scikit-learn
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-learn, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: What is your python version can you type in cmd `python --version`

Comment: I got -Python 3.10.1

Comment: from [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/) i can see it does not support python 3.10

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could use `pipwin` to install the appropriate build for your operating system and specific version of Python. Just run the commands

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install scikit-learn
```

in an elevated terminal.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do go to this [URL](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn) and search for `Scikit-learn`. It support wheel file for `python 3.10`

You can download files there are two types of file

1. scikit_learn‑0.24.2‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl
2. scikit_learn‑0.24.2‑cp310‑cp310‑win32.whl

So according to your python bit version you can download wheel file

and give full path for installing in cmd like (This for `Python 64-bit` so):

```
pip install filepath\scikit_learn‑0.24.2‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl
```

For version `1.0.1` install file according to python version with `pip` command as above.

```
scikit_learn‑1.0.1‑cp310‑cp310‑win32.whl
scikit_learn‑1.0.1‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: After that I am getting this: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _openmp_helpers: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: What is your python bit version

Comment: It is 64 bit , [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: Can you try out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59206367/however-import-sklearn-still-gives-me-error-more-details-are-given-below-how)  from SO!

Comment: I have the same problem and will try your solution. Thanks. However, there are also whl files starting with scikit_learn‑1.0.1‑cp310 in the list. Why should we prefer 0.24.2 to 1.0.1? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: yes you take that file and install it at that time i think 1.0.1 wheel file was not there in list