# pip install ppscore fails

Tags: python, pip

I'm running Python 3.10.6 on Windows 10 (64-bit), and I've been trying to pip install ppscore without any luck. I've got scikit-learn 1.1.1 already installed. I have looked at similar previous questions [here] ([ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-learn, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70303758/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-scikit-learn-which-is-required-to-install-pyp)) and whilst it helped with making progress with some of the problems during the pip install, I still cannot seem to get a clean and complete install of the package. Would appreciate any pointers, thanks.

```
C:\Users\Jones>pip install -U ppscore
Collecting ppscore
  Using cached ppscore-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting scikit-learn<1.0.0,>=0.20.2
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.24.2.tar.gz (7.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pandas<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 in c:\users\jones\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from ppscore) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\users\jones\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pandas<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->ppscore) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\jones\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pandas<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->ppscore) (2022.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in c:\users\jones\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pandas<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->ppscore) (1.23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\jones\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn<1.0.0,>=0.20.2->ppscore) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.19.1 in c:\users\jones\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn<1.0.0,>=0.20.2->ppscore) (1.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\jones\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn<1.0.0,>=0.20.2->ppscore) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\jones\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->ppscore) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-learn
  Building wheel for scikit-learn (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for scikit-learn (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1703 lines of output]
      Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
      <string>:116: DeprecationWarning:

        `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
        of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
        Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
        It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
        For more details, see:
          https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html


      INFO: No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      INFO: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt /Tctest_program.c /Foobjects\test_program.obj
      INFO: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=1 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\ATLMFC\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x64 objects\test_program.obj /OUT:test_program.exe
      INFO: No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      INFO: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt /Tctest_program.c /Foobjects\test_program.obj /openmp
      INFO: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=1 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\ATLMFC\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x64 objects\test_program.obj /OUT:test_program.exe /openmp
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running config_cc
      INFO: unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      INFO: unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      ...
      running build_clib
      INFO: No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      INFO: customize MSVCCompiler
      WARN: Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler
      INFO: customize MSVCCompiler using build_clib
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.cc_test_flags[1073] : testing flags (/O2)
      ...
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.cc_test_flags[1073] : testing flags (/WX)
      WARN: CCompilerOpt.__init__[1240] : feature 'AVX512_KNL' is disabled, MSVC compiler doesn't support it
      WARN: CCompilerOpt.__init__[1240] : feature 'AVX512_KNM' is disabled, MSVC compiler doesn't support it
      ...
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.generate_dispatch_header[2353] : generate CPU dispatch header: (build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\distutils\include\npy_cpu_dispatch_config.h)
      WARN: CCompilerOpt.generate_dispatch_header[2362] : dispatch header dir build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\distutils\include does not exist, creating it
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_extra_checks[1627] : Testing extra checks for feature 'AVX512F' (AVX512F_REDUCE)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_extra_checks[1627] : Testing extra checks for feature 'AVX512_SKX' (AVX512BW_MASK AVX512DQ_MASK)
      ...
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\sklearn\datasets\tests\data\openml\292
      copying sklearn\datasets\tests\data\openml\292\api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-australian-limit-2-data_version-1.json.gz -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\sklearn\datasets\tests\data\openml\292
      copying sklearn\datasets\tests\data\openml\292\api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-australian-limit-2-status-active-.json.gz -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\sklearn\datasets\tests\data\openml\292
      copying sklearn\datasets\tests\data\openml\292\api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-australian-limit-2-data_version-1-status-deactivated.json.gz -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\sklearn\datasets\tests\data\openml\292
      error: could not create 'build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\sklearn\datasets\tests\data\openml\292\api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-australian-limit-2-data_version-1-status-deactivated.json.gz': No such file or directory
      INFO:
      ########### EXT COMPILER OPTIMIZATION ###########
      INFO: Platform      :
        Architecture: x64
        Compiler    : msvc

      CPU baseline  :
        Requested   : 'min'
        Enabled     : SSE SSE2 SSE3
        Flags       : none
        Extra checks: none

      CPU dispatch  :
        Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'
        Enabled     : SSSE3 SSE41 POPCNT SSE42 AVX F16C FMA3 AVX2 AVX512F AVX512CD AVX512_SKX AVX512_CLX AVX512_CNL AVX512_ICL
        Generated   : none
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.cache_flush[857] : write cache to path -> C:\Users\Jones\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f_40uqo4\scikit-learn_9a90911f02d946e18041e6e7b0335d1d\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\ccompiler_opt_cache_ext.py
      INFO:
      ########### CLIB COMPILER OPTIMIZATION ###########
      INFO: Platform      :
        Architecture: x64
        Compiler    : msvc

      CPU baseline  :
        Requested   : 'min'
        Enabled     : SSE SSE2 SSE3
        Flags       : none
        Extra checks: none

      CPU dispatch  :
        Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'
        Enabled     : SSSE3 SSE41 POPCNT SSE42 AVX F16C FMA3 AVX2 AVX512F AVX512CD AVX512_SKX AVX512_CLX AVX512_CNL AVX512_ICL
        Generated   : none
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.cache_flush[857] : write cache to path -> C:\Users\Jones\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f_40uqo4\scikit-learn_9a90911f02d946e18041e6e7b0335d1d\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\ccompiler_opt_cache_clib.py
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn
Failed to build scikit-learn
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-learn, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Can you try uninstalling `sklearn` and then installing `ppscore`?

Comment: Uninstalled sklearn (and scikit-learn), and then attempted pip install ppscore just now. Same result/problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So....downgraded my python version from v3.10.6 to v3.9.0 on a conda test environment, and then ppscore installs successfully. Sigh!

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/discussions/21931